# How to calculate energy of an OFDM signal?

Tags: fft, ofdm

What is the difference between power and energy of OFDM signal. How to calculate energy of an OFDM signal, if we consider OFDM symbol size is 64, and QPSK is used as modulation scheme?

Comment: An OFDM signal is still a regular signal. Its power and energy can be calculated the same way as those of any other signal. Can you describe what is the specific problem you're having with this problem?

Comment: Actually I want to show the energy saving due to PAPR reduction.

Comment: @ShakirHossain you should definitely elaborate on that in your question, not in the comments. Also, **what** PAPR reduction technology are you employing? It's not like there's one single method to reduce PAPR... Even more importantly, power saving due to PAPR depends on your amplifiers semiconductor technology and your linearity requirements, so no answer given here can help you unless you take much much more physical things into consideration.